# Diff. between with www & without www

Tags: domains, google-search-console

Is there any diff. if I submit my site to google with www or without www?

Which is best way to submit from above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. However, it's good practice to choose one or the other and stick to it - allowing for both may cause issues with ranking.

You can ensure that your website sticks to one or the other by redirecting all requests to the one you have chosen. Here is an example, which ensures all requests to google.co.uk get redirected to www.google.co.uk - it also ensures that the index page is consistently /:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.google\.co\.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html|php|htm)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule . http://www.google.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

You can generate your own using this tool and entering your canonical domain:

http://www.thefreshuk.com/tools/htaccess-gen.html